# Echo data from two different mysql tables using php

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to display data from two different mysql tables on my website using php.

My aim is to display a match schedule with information from two tables. The first one includes all the teams plus their ID, the second includes all details on the games. I now want to "replace" the "home_id" and "away_id" fields with the respective team names from the first table.

The tables look as follows:

```
table "teams"
id  name
-----------
 1  Team 1
 2  Team 2
 3  Team 3
 4  Team 4
 ...

table "matchschedule"
id   home_id   away_id   goals_home   goals_away   date
 1      1         2          0             2       2016-05-05
 2      3         4          2             1       2016-05-06
 ...
```

With the following query I'm getting the required data within phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT 
    date, home.name, sp.goals_home, away.name, sp.goals_away 
FROM 
    matchschedule sp 
INNER JOIN 
    teams home on sp.home = home.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    teams away on sp.away = away.id
```

However, when I implement this query into my website and add the code below to display the data the fields "home.name" and "away.name" are always empty. What do I need to change in order to get the team names displayed?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  ?>

  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <?php
        echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['home.name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['goals_home']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['away.name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['goals_away']."</td>";
      ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Final result (with missing info for both team names):

```
2016-05-05  []  0  []  2
2016-05-06  []  2  []  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when in query you request `home.name` mysql return to php column with title `name` and you can not reach that column using `home.name` anymore. And same for `away.name`.

That's why you need to set proper name for returned columns.

Change your query to:

```
SELECT 
    date, home.name home_name, sp.goals_home, away.name away_name, sp.goals_away 
FROM 
    matchschedule sp 
INNER JOIN 
    teams home on sp.home = home.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    teams away on sp.away = away.id
```

and call those columns in php like:

```
    echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['home_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['goals_home']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['away_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['goals_away']."</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your table strcture, you should do the following :

```
SELECT 
    date, home.name AS homeName, sp.goals_home, away.name AS awayName, sp.goals_away 
FROM 
    matchschedule sp 
INNER JOIN 
    teams home on sp.home_id = home.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    teams away on sp.away_id = away.id
```

So basically replace **sp.home** by **sp.home_id** and **sp.away** by **sp.away_id** and change the fields name as you have the same fields name in your tables.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly fine.